# Is -X redundant if -Y is also specified when running ssh?

Tags: ssh

Is there any difference between the following two commands?

```
ssh -XY <USER>@<HOST>
ssh  -Y <USER>@<HOST>
```

In my experience, the answer to this question appears to be "no", but I can't say for sure.

(AFAICT, the documentation does not explicitly answer this question.)

Comment: If `-X` and `-Y` overrides each other, then `-YX` is the same as just `-X` while `-XY` is the same as just `-Y`, but I can't test this.

Comment: Use `-vvv` and diff the output, perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this University of Maryland website](http://hpcf.umbc.edu/general-productivity/running-x-windows-programs-remotely/),

> Note that a “-X” may be used instead of “-Y” to make an X connection. There are subtle differences between the two, where use of “-Y” implies a higher level of trust in the remote machine, but may not always be available. You may use both flags together to ensure an X connection is made.